# How i track user in map using Universal windows application(UWP)?

Tags: uwp, uwp-maps

Mainpage.xaml

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 0 0 0">
        <Button x:Name="TrackLocationButton" Margin="120 20 0 0" Content="track location" Click="TrackLocationButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Maps:MapControl x:Name="MapControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" Margin="30 100 0 0" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Mainpage.cs

```
    public double lat;
    public double lon;
    public int Accurancy;
    // Proides access to location data
    private Geolocator _geolocator = null;


    private void UpdateLocationData(Geoposition position)
    {
        if (position == null)
        {
            lat = 0;
            lon = 0;
            Accurancy = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            lat = position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
            lon = position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
            Accurancy = Convert.ToInt32(position.Coordinate.Accuracy);
            AddLocation(lat, lon);
        }
    }

    private void AddLocation(double s,double s2)
    {
        BasicGeoposition location = new BasicGeoposition();
        location.Latitude = s;
        location.Longitude = s2;
        MapIcon mapIcon;
        mapIcon = new MapIcon();
        if (mapIcon != null)
        {
            MapControl1.MapElements.Remove(mapIcon);
        }
        mapIcon.Location = new Geopoint(location);
        mapIcon.Title = "Azar";
        MapControl1.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);
        MapControl1.Center = new Geopoint(location);
    }

    private async void TrackLocationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Request permission to access location
        var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

        switch (accessStatus)
        {
            case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed;
            _geolocator = new Geolocator { ReportInterval = 2000 };
            _geolocator.PositionChanged += OnPositionChanged;
            _geolocator.StatusChanged += OnStatusChanged;            
        }
    }

    private async void OnStatusChanged(Geolocator sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            switch (e.Status)
            {
                case PositionStatus.Ready:
                      // message
                    break;

                case PositionStatus.Initializing:
                   // message
                    break;

                case PositionStatus.NoData:
                   // message
                    break;

                case PositionStatus.Disabled:
                // message
                    break;

                case PositionStatus.NotInitialized:
                  // message
                    break;

                case PositionStatus.NotAvailable:
                    // message
                    break;

                default:
                    // message
                    break;
            }
        });
    }


    private async void OnPositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            UpdateLocationData(e.Position);
        });

    }
```

I tried track the user and pin the route of start and destination point in map control, then i want to user travel the route when if the user change path, i get alert? so how do i do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're asking. Could you try reading [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rephrasing your question?

Comment: I want tracking the user location in map when if user change route then user will receive notification in the application

Comment: @Azarudeen have you got solution for this? If then please share

Answer (score 0):

The map control currently has no concept of a current user location or API for displaying user position or tracking them. Routes are added by the calling application either through the RouteView object or by adding a polyline directly.